# How does one use Docker DIND and AWS CLI together as a service

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I use Gitlab CI to deploy to AWS ECS. As such, I need two things from the Gitlab environment:

- Docker-in-Docker - so I can run **docker build** etc
- AWS CLI - to deploy to ECS with the AWS CLI

This is a snippet of my stage in Gitlab CI. Although the AWS CLI bit doesn't make sense, it is enough to demonstrate the problem I am facing:

```
dockerise-dev:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.12
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.12-dind
    - name: amazon/aws-cli:2.15.26
      entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - docker build .
    - aws s3 ls
```

But I get the error below:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: no command specified (docker.go:436:0s)
```

How do i make use of the amazon/aws-cli:2.15.26 as a service so I don't have to install aws cli separately?

Thanks

Comment: You can't really use [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) that way. They're just containers connected by network to your job. You should have AWS CLI installed in the image used in `image:` or install it during your job.